# How do I add multiple images in StackPanel WPF from Folder?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, wpfdatagrid

I want to give `folder path` and from that folder path If That `folder contains 3 images` I want to `display those 3 images` into `StackPanel WPF Form`

I tried something like below which works fine for one image but how can load all the images from given folder?

```
<Window x:Class="wpfBug.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
    <StackPanel Name="sp">
    </StackPanel>
</Window>



private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Image i = new Image();
            BitmapImage src = new BitmapImage();
            src.BeginInit();
            src.UriSource = new Uri("mypic.png", UriKind.Relative);
            // how to load all images from given folder?
            src.EndInit();
            i.Source = src;
            i.Stretch = Stretch.Uniform;
            //int q = src.PixelHeight;        // Image loads here
            sp.Children.Add(i);
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use an `ItemsControl` like shown below. It uses a vertical StackPanel as default panel for its items.

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="imageItems">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Image Source="{Binding}" Margin="5"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Set the `ItemsSource` of the ItemsControl like this:

```
imageItems.ItemsSource = Directory.EnumerateFiles(FOLDERPATH, "*.png");
```

The conversion from path string to `ImageSource` is performed by built-in type conversion in WPF.

---

You may use a different ItemsPanel like this:

```
<ItemsControl ...>
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    ...
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: I think all images are loasing on each other :(
how can I make a space in between two images ?

Comment: Set their Margin property.

Comment: still only one image is displayed :O strange I have written `imageItems.ItemsSource = Directory.EnumerateFiles(FOLDERPATH, "*.png");` on `Window_Loaded`

Comment: damn it i have used   <ItemsControl x:Name="imageItems" Height="120" Width="120"  Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2">
how to fix this layout issue

Comment: Not sure what you mean. If you set the size of the ItemsControl you should make sure that the Images can fit into its size. You may give the Image controls an appropriate (smaller) size. Or put the ItemsControl in a ScrollViewer.

Comment: I check with total new application also it is showing only 1 image , which is 1st image . margin does not work :( any other solution ?

Comment: Replace ItemsSource by ListBox. It has a vertical ScrollBar by default. If it also shows only one image, then there is only one (png) in your folder.

Comment: debugger shows multiple images gets into result for `imageItems.ItemsSource`