# How to create images in a Foreach Loop

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a List of objects and i want to create a Foreach loop which create images on my MainWindow separated by 50 pixels for example. I don't know if I have to create them in the desgner itself or if there's a way to create then place the images the one below the other in a command.
For example i have:

```
List<string> URIS = new List<string>();

foreach (var i in URIS) 
{
    //New image in MainWindow with source i
}
```

Remember that I want a "list" of images in my Window so that every image is below the last one.

Comment: Create them, set their position, and add them to the form's `Controls` collection.

Comment: Take a look at ItemsControl. Set (or bind) its ItemsSource property to your URI list. Put an Image control in its ItemTemplate and set the Image's Source property like `<Image Source="{Binding}"/>`.

Comment: Seems like you are talking chinese to me :/

Comment: Check out this post.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/347614/wpf-image-resources

Comment: @Ay0m3 If that sounds chinese, start reading here: [Data Templating Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521(v=vs.100).aspx). There's also plenty of Q&A here on StackOverflow about the topic, e.g. this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34557467/1136211

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into the `ItemsControl`. It has an `ItemsSource` property that takes a list and lays out its items into a visual list. You can use the `ItemTemplate` property to control exactly what type of visual is created from each list item, including things like spacing.