# Dynamic Loading of Larger Images in WPF

Tags: wpf

I have a strange issue with WPF, I was loading images from the disk at runtime and adding them to a Canvas container. My Image size is more than 20MB. I need to display 20 to 30 images in one window and I want to display images in full clearity. My Problem is some images are not displayed. Here below my code

```
for (var i = 0; i < Count; i++)
{
   BitmapImage bmp=new BitmapImage(new Uri(ImagePath, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
   Image imageControl = new Image();
   imageControl.Source = bmp;
   MyCanvas.Children.Add(imageControl);            
}
```

Comment: *"Image size is more than 20MB"* - what does that mean exactly? Is it the size of a JPG file, which would indicate images with more than 20 megapixels? As a note, you should not create the Image elements in code behind. Instead, use an ItemsControl with an Image element in the ItemTemplate, and bind its ItemsSource to a collection of file path strings, e.g. like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34557467/1136211

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="imageLists">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Image Source="{Binding}" Width="500" Margin="15"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Set the ItemsSource of the ItemsControl like this:

```
imageLists.ItemsSource = Directory.EnumerateFiles(FOLDERPATH, "*.*");
```